# How to auto-copy to removable device?

Tags: 16.04, usb, backup, sync, automatic

I've got data on my HDD that needs to be backed up. Lets say that it's everything in `folder a`. On a USB stick there's a copy of `folder a`, that should be updated automatically whenever the stick is mounted. How can this be done automatically?

Comment: It would be good if there was a visible indication to the user that the copying has finished too...

Answer (score 1):

Create a udev rule for when the drive is inserted, and run your backup routine (rsync or other procedure on the device).

This is a crude example to get you started.

The rule to call your backup script (`/etc/udev/rules.d/10-local.rules`):

```
ACTION=="add", RUN+="/bin/sh -c 'exec /home/userid/backupscript.sh & > /home/userid/Desktop/test.out'"
```

Replace `userid` above with your userid, or place the script in a different  path.

The backup script:

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                       

templine=/tmp/line.$$

backuproutine () {
    # backup rountine goes here                                                                   
    timestamp=$(date)
    message="This is the Backup noice."
    device=$(mount | egrep "sd.1")
    echo -e "$timestamp:$message\n$device" > $templine
    cat $templine >> /home/userid/Desktop/backupnotice.txt
}

backuproutine
rm $templine
```

This is a crude script, but something to get you started.

This command will provide details on how to use the **udev** rules.

```
man udev
```

Comment: Would this script attempt to backup to _any_ new device inserted? It would seem like backing up _might_ only be desired to a very specific USB stick (though @iam4k33m can probably clarify).

Comment: The purpose of the answer is to show an example to be used as a template for the user to actual program the actions.  The backup function would analyze the mount and determine how to handle the results.  All drives has unique identification properties.  The user can manually label the partition  and have the script identify it by that label or use the UUID of the partition.  Put a pendrive in your computer and look at the output of `lsblk -o name,mountpoint,label,size,fstype`.