# Find command works in terminal but not in automatic shell script

Tags: command-line, bash, usb, scripts

I am writing a script that automatically copies sqlite files from my computer to a USB stick whenever the stick is inserted. It makes a new directory on the USB that takes the hostname of the computer, as I will be downloading from multiple computers.

The script is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Set the source folder to download from
src_dir="/home/atlas/atlas/runs/server"

# Define hostname 
usb_hostname=$(cat /etc/hostname)

# Find USB path
usb_path=$(find /media/atlas/*/ -maxdepth 0 -type d -print -quit)
echo "USB path = $usb_path"

# Set the destination 
dest_dir=$usb_path$usb_hostname

# Mount the USB device
sudo mount -t vfat /dev/sd?1 dest_dir

# Create a directory on the USB stick 
sudo mkdir -p $dest_dir

# Copy the files with 'sqlite' in the extension from the source folder to the destination folder
find $src_dir -type f -iname "*sqlite*" -exec cp {} $dest_dir \;

# Unmount the USB device
sudo umount dest_dir
```

The script works perfectly when I run it in terminal, however when it runs on insertion it fails on the 'find' command (line 'usb_path ='), where it returns 'No such file or directory'.

Things I have tried:

- Setting 'sleep 5' at the start of the script to allow time to mount; I've extended the time of this too with no change
- Checking permissions for the script to access the /media/atlas/ directory
- There are no errors in the syslog file
- 'atlas' is my user; if I change this to $(whoami) the script changes the path to /media/root/ and also cannot find any directory
- The USB device is mounted correctly (as I said, the script works fine from terminal)
- I've checked and the script does recognise /media/atlas, it just doesn't recognise any sub-directories

I'm at my wits end here. I can see that the problem is that when automatically run, the shell script can't find any directories within /media/atlas/ but I have no idea why. Any suggestions would be very much appreciated.

Comment: I'm confused about what you're trying to do here - if the USB doesn't get automounted under /media/atlas/ then you won't be able to find it with `find` - but if it does get automounted, why would you want to mount it again?

Comment: "*I am writing a script that automatically copies sqlite files from my computer to a USB stick **whenever the stick is inserted***" ... You  are probably using a udev rule for that ... If so, then it wont work ... Plus the way you detect the partition on the USB by arbitrarily guessing `/dev/sd?1` (I understand you might have only NVME or SSD so the naming is different) but still this is not the way to go ... See for example [Different behaviour of bash script in udev](https://askubuntu.com/q/1417539)

Comment: The mounting lines are a mistake then on my part - as is probably apparent I am very new to this. If I remove the mount commands the script still works in terminal, but not via udev.

To clarify, does this mean my aim here is not possible? I would like to set my computer up so that when a USB is inserted, files automatically copy from the computer to the USB. I thought a udev rule was the correct approach - such as was suggested here - https://askubuntu.com/questions/876028/how-to-auto-copy-to-removable-device - but it sounds like this circularity makes this impossible (at least via udev).

Comment: "*To clarify, does this mean my aim here is not possible?*" … Not with a udev rule … See my answer in the post I linked above for how to automatically detect and mount a USB disk partition with a bash script the right way … Example template  scripts that you can build on and modify to your needs are included in the answer.